# Method outputs a value without being "S.O.P'd" + get/set method issues

Tags: java, arrays, methods

This is my initialize case. When it runs, it takes the inputs the user entered and creates an "image" with it:

```
case INITIALIZE:
{
    row = Integer.parseInt(array[1]);
    column = Integer.parseInt(array[2]);
    initializeImage(row, column);
    break;
}
```

In this case, the initializeImage method is called:

```
public static void initializeImage (int row, int column)
{        
    char[][] image = new char[row][column];
    for (int i = 0; i < column; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < row; j++)
        {
            image[j][i] = WHITE;
            System.out.print(image[j][i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    setImage(image);
}
```

This method creates the image, but I don't think it should output the array since it has a void return type. Now it leads to the `setImage` method:

```
public static void setImage(char[][] newImage)
{
    newImage = image;
}
```

This method also has a void return type, so I don't think it could output the array. If you're wondering why I have this method, I have a number of other methods that update/change the image. This method keeps track of the most current image.

**The array is not supposed to be displayed when the `INITIALIZE` case is executed, yet it is. How can I stop this issue?.**

If you don't mind me asking another question, this is my case SAVE. SAVE is executed when the user wants to see the output.

```
case SAVE:
{
    System.out.println(getImage());
    break;
}
```

It's supposed to display the image from the `getImage()` method

```
public static char[][] getImage()
{
    return newImage;
}
```

The method is supposed to get the value for newImage from the setImage() method. Instead, `newImage` gets the value (or lack thereof) null. I've looked into pass-by references and pass-by values but I didn't understand the idea. Or more specifically, how to implement them in this case. I declared newImage like so:

```
public static char[][] newImage;
```

My logic was that since it is public, the `getImage()` method would be able to use the `newImage` array. That was until I realized that I used `char[][] newImage` as a parameter in `setImage(). Now I feel I am at an impasse. **How could I change my get/set methods so that it can return the most current image successfully.**

I'm not sure what Stack Overflow's policy is on asking two questions in one thread. If necessary, I edit this portion out and ask separately.

Any and all help would be most appreciated!

Edit: Input and output

What it currently looks like

```
I 2 3
00
00
00
S one
null
```

What it should look like:

```
I 2 3
S one
00
00
00
```

Edit: new `setImage()` method:

```
public static void setImage(char[][] newImage)
{
    this.newImage = newImage;
}
```

It still gives the error "Non static this cannot be referenced from a static context."

Comment: If I understand correctly, the program is printing all the elements of the array. Right?

Comment: Yes. I just want it to do that when the SAVE case is executed.

Comment: Hmmm... could you provide us with the code you have, then? (Remember to post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please...)

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, don't use initializeImage method but use

```
    char[][] image = new char[row][column];
    setImage(image);
```

instead of initializeImage() so it doesn't print yet the char[][] is set.

And for your second question, in the set image switch

```
newImage = image;
```

to

```
image = newImage;
```

Therefore, image will always be the most updated version of an image, and you can use image anywhere else and it will be the most updated.

Comment: I can't remove the initializeImage method because I need it to create the image. I tried what you suggested for the second question, but it still returns null. I'm sure it's because I declared newImage beforehand, so I removed that. Now it would be a matter of using the value from setImage() in getImage. I'm not sure how to go about doing that though. Thank you, by the way.

Comment: Wouldn't using what I said for your second question answer it, what is the problem that happens? Also fixed the first question

Comment: For your first suggestion, should I replace the call to the initializeImage() method with what you said? If so, then where would the image be created? As for the second question, I updated the original post with the inputs and outputs. The first input/output is what happened even after I tried your suggestion

Comment: First question: NO What I mean is that just inside the INITIALIZER case don't use initalizeImage. Second question to get rid of the error don't use this, it won't work in your context, in your case use YourClassName.newImage, that or rename the variable. I don't see why "S one" is coming in at the wrong time though

Answer (score 0):

Your logic seems to be a little flawed: void methods do have the ability to output data, just like return methods. For example, the `printStackTrace()` method of the `Throwable` class is a void method, yet it can print an entire stack trace, which can contain a lot of data. So if you don't want your array to be printed, just remove the `System.out.print(image[j][i])` statement from your `for` loop in your `initializeImage` method.

In regards to the `getImage` method returning null, take another look at your `setImage` method. The variable `image` is assigning some value to `newImage` (which is likely a null value). So ultimately your `getImage` method will return the value stored in `newImage`, which is null.

In your `setImage` method, try renaming your method parameter. For example:

```
public static void setImage(char[][] image)
{
    newImage = image;
}
```

Comment: I don't have another class instance called newImage. I do have the instance field public static char[][] newImage. I've tried doing this.newImage = newImage, but it gives the error "non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context."

Comment: Sorry id I am becoming a bother, but I don't quite understand what you mean by "This way you can set the class variable newImage to the char[][] method parameter newImage". I updated the original post to include my current setImage() method.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed that setImage was an instance method. But couldn't you alter the name of the method parameter? Could you rename it to `image` (so you'd have `public static void setImage(char[][] image) { newImage = image; }`)?

Comment: I renamed the parameter char[][] newImage to char[][] image and the error is gone, but it still returns null when getImage is called.

Comment: What I meant was that `newImage` would be set to the value stored in the method parameter. See my edited post. And you're not being a bother :)

Comment: This is what my get and set methods look like now: [link](http://imgur.com/p77PXC8)